# Read specific data from a .txt file JAVA

Tags: java, file

I have a problem. I'm trying to read a large .txt file, but I don't need every piece of data that's inside.

My .txt file looks something like this:

> 8000000  abcdefg  hijklmn word word letter

I only need, let's say, the number and the first two text positions: "abcdefg" and "hijklmn" and write it to another file after that. I don't know how to read and write just the data that I need.

Here is my code so far:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("position2.txt"));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("position.txt"));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine())!= null){
        if(line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().equals("\n")){
            continue;
        }else{
            //bw.write(line + "\n");
            String[] data = line.split(" ");
            bw.write(data[0] + " " + data[1] + " " + data[2] + "\n");
        }

    }

    br.close();
    bw.close();

}
```

Can you give me some sugestions ?
Thanks in advance

UPDATE: 
My .txt files are a bit weird. Using the code above works great when there is only one single " " between them. My files can have a \t or more spaces, or a \t and some spaces between the words. Ho can I proceed now ?

Comment: Use `split` to spit the string and extract the indexes you're interested in and put them in the new file.

Comment: Suggestion 1: split by space and re-compose the first 3 elements of the result array. Suggestion 2: use regex to extract the part that you need out of the string (less efficient)

Comment: @alfasin Why is that less efficient? Because it uses a regular expression? Check the `split` function again: The parameter **is** a regular expression.

Comment: @alfasin If you think/care that `split` is more efficient than a regular expression, then you shouldn't suggest either, but use `indexOf` instead, because that's even more efficient. More efficient search than the regex of a space, and eliminates the need to allocate an array for the result. If you care about efficiency (without profiling), go all the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of you data, you have a few options.

If the lines are simple space-separated values like shown, the simplest is to split the text, and write the values you want to keep to the new file:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] values = line.split(" ");
        if (values.length >= 3)
            bw.write(values[0] + ' ' + values[1] + ' ' + values[2] + '\n');
    }
}
```

If the values might be more complex, you could use a regular expression:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+ \\w+ \\w+)");
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if (m.find())
            bw.write(m.group(1) + '\n');
    }
}
```

This ensures that first value is digits only, and second and third values are word-characters only (`a-z A-Z _ 0-9`).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. For some reason I can't write to the file. I've update my code, can you look at it ?

Comment: @OlarAndrei If you get an error, what is it? If your code creates the file, but it's empty, it's because you didn't `close()` the writer (and the reader). That's why I added the try-with-resources in my code samples.

Comment: Thank you. It was because I didn't close them. Well, my .txt files are a bit weird. The actual file doeas not have one single space between the words. It can have one or two \t or more spaces. How can I proceed in such a case, where i can't split the line equally ?

Comment: @OlarAndrei Is it like a tab-separated file, where two tabs mean an empty value?

Comment: Well not, let me give you an example:
"100000     i need to go home     i am hungry"
I need to read them and save them as 3 Strings: String1: "100000"
String2: "i need to go home"
String3: "i am hungry"
Is there a regular expression that can do this ?

Comment: How do you know it's the space between `home` and `i` that should be the split?

Comment: The .txt file is kind o a mapping. So for id: 100000 you have 2 types of descriptions: description1:"i need to go home"  and description2: "i am hungry". To be more precise: Between the id and the first description there are 7 spaces and 1 tab, and between description1 and description2 there are 1 or 2 spaces.

Comment: Without a definitive definition, there's nothing a program can do. If you have a definition definition, try reading up on [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to see what it can do.

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
     String[] res = line.split(" ");
     bw.write(res[0] + " " + res[1] + " " + res[2] + "\n"); // the first three words...
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Simply split each line to words, and store each word as an entry in the array res, now that we have an array of words take the first three words as requested in the question, honestly i thought it was too obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all lines of your text file follow the structure you described then you could do this:
Replace FILE_PATH with your actual file path.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("FILE_PATH/myfile.txt"));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("FILE_PATH/myfile2.txt"));
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = reader.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");

            writer.println(tokens[0] + ", " + tokens[1] + ", " + tokens[2]);
        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

You'll get something like:
word0, word1, word2

Answer (score 0):

If your files are really huge (above 50-100 MB maybe GBs) and you are sure that the first word is a number and you need two words after that I would suggest you to read one line and iterate through that string. Stop when you find 3rd space.

```
String str = readLine();
int num_spaces = 0, cnt = 0;
String arr[] = new String[3];
while(num_spaces < 3){
    if(str.charAt(cnt) == ' '){
        num_space++;
    }
    else{
        arr[num_space] += str.charAt(cnt);
    }
}
```

If your data is couple of MB only or have a lot of numbers inside, no need to worry about iterating char by char. Just `read line by line and split lines then check the words` as it is mentioned